# Query on non-key attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

It appears that dynamodb's `query` method must include the partition key as part of the filter. How can a query be performed if you do not know the partition key?

For example, you have a User table with the attribute `userid` set as the partition key. Now we want to look up a user by their phone number. Is it possible to perform the query without the partition key? Using the `scan` method, this goal can be achieved, but at the expense of pulling every item from the table before the filter is applied, as far as I know.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll need to set up a [global secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) (GSI), using your `phoneNumber` column as the index hash key.

You can create a GSI by calling [UpdateTable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html).

Once you create the index, you'll be able to call [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) with your `IndexName`, to pull user records based on the phone number.

Comment: Ah, I must have overlooked that. Perfect!

Comment: What if I want to query based on multiple attributes, and the set of those attributes may vary per request (for example one time I can query based on 2 attributes, next time on 5, next time on 1, and so on)? Does your suggestion work in this scenario also?

Comment: @JoseQuijada Querying on arbitrary combinations of keys is not something DynamoDB supports. If you have a few fixed multi-key queries you need to perform, you should likely create compound attributes: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/querying-on-multiple-attributes-in-amazon-dynamodb/